# Accessing Cloud Datastore from Qt app

Tags: qt, pyqt, google-cloud-endpoints, qtnetwork, endpoints-proto-datastore

I've developed a REST API back end using Endpoints-Proto-Datastore, which wraps the Cloud Endpoints Python API. I'm starting to look at Qt and trying to get an idea what will be involved in accessing my API from the Qt networking or other library. Might it be nearly as straightforward as is making the calls from the command line using the Python Client library, which even handles OAuth2 flows? This would be very nice. I might use PyQt if this makes things simpler.

Comment: I think you left your Cloud to Butt extension on.

Comment: Thanks. It seems my butt is in places it really shouldn't be.

Comment: BTW, if it's not too unrelated, I'd like to share that looking over Qt docs has been a breath of fresh air after years of web components and, recently, Angular and React. I doubt I'll be looking back, at the crazy browser stack. :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I located [this document](https://google.github.io/google-api-cpp-client/latest/start/get_started.html) which gives a pretty good overview for my purposes:

"The Google APIs Client Library for C++ will automatically take care of many of the tedious details for interpreting and complying with the discovery documents so that you can write simpler and familiar C++ code."

Now it's a matter of building and installing the C++ client and then figuring out how to generate the client library and access it from a Qt application. But that is beyond the scope of this question.

Answer (score 1):

Your Endpoints service can generate an OpenAPI specification file which describes the API. Once you do this, there are many OpenAPI-compatible packages which can generate client code for you.

Comment: Thanks. Is this different than the API discovery document?

Comment: It is, yes. The discovery document is an older approach; it may work for your needs, but before adopting it, make sure you won't have to move to something else soon.

Comment: Good point. I can't find anything from Google about generating an OpenAPI spec file from an Endpoints API.

Comment: That's covered here: https://cloud.google.com/endpoints/docs/frameworks/python/adding-api-management

Comment: I see it! You rock!